# google app script to send new event from sheet to calendar have problems with correct trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a problem with my script trigger.

Initial situation:
I use a web form to send the period, location, title and description of a new appointment to a Google spreadsheet from my web space.

In this table (input) I process the received data and then pass it on to trigger (onchange) in another table (output).

Here is my problem, it used to work, but now it doesn't.

The trigger will probably be executed before all the data in the table (output) is available.
Anyway, this is how I define the following error message:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createEvent') at calendar entry_func(Output:22:31)

However, if I run the script to enter the calendar manually in the editor, it works.

I have 2 approaches to solve this problem:

Variant 1: If there is the possibility to start the script via a link.
Variant 2: With a self-defined trigger that only starts when the required cells of the output table have been completely updated, so I think with a time delay.

If I were to install a trigger that would select every xx minutes, etc., I always have multiple entries and that is no longer necessary.

Maybe someone could help me there.

OK i try to set my question other.
i get mey form datas  fom my page with this code:

html form datas go to the hidden values:

```
<form  name="Sendtosheet">
    <input type="hidden" name="Timestamp"     value="<?=$timestamp;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Startdatum"    value="<?=$startdatum;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Startzeit"     value="<?=$startzeit;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Enddatum"      value="<?=$enddatum;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Endzeit"       value="<?=$endzeit;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Titel"         value="<?=$titel;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Beschreibung"  value="<?=$beschreibung;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="Adresse"       value="<?=$pluscode;?>">
</form>
<script>
const scriptURL = 'scriptlink'
const form = document.forms['Sendtosheet']
fetch(scriptURL, {method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
.then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
.catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
</script>
```

the receiving script to the target table of this script

are this:

```
var sheetName = 'Eingang'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
function intialSetup () 
  {
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
  }
function doPost (e)
  {
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
    lock.tryLock(10000)
    try
      {
        var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
        var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)
        var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
        var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
        var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]}) 
        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
        return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
      }
    catch (e)
      {
        return ContentService
        .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
      }
    finally
      {
        lock.releaseLock()
      }
  }
```

ok this runs perfect

because i'm just a beginner and all this is basically too difficult for me,
i can understand the course of the code but no plan how i can connect it to the next one.

To set a trigger, I created a new table with which I run the following script onchange

```
function Kalendereintrag_func() 
  {
    var mappe = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Eingang");
    var KalenderID = 'xxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com';
    var meinKalender = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(KalenderID);
    var Startdatum = mappe.getRange('K2').getValue();
    var Startzeit = mappe.getRange('L2').getValue();
    var Enddatum = mappe.getRange('M2').getValue();
    var Endzeit = mappe.getRange('N2').getValue();
  
    var Dienstbeginn = new Date(Startdatum);
        Dienstbeginn.setHours(Startzeit.getHours());
        Dienstbeginn.setMinutes(Startzeit.getMinutes());
  
    var Dienstende = new Date(Enddatum);
        Dienstende.setHours(Endzeit.getHours());
        Dienstende.setMinutes(Endzeit.getMinutes());
  
    var Titel = mappe.getRange('O2').getValue();
    var Beschreibung = mappe.getRange('P2').getValue();
    var Ort = mappe.getRange('Q2').getValue();

    var Termin = meinKalender.createEvent(Titel, Dienstbeginn, Dienstende, { description: Beschreibung, location: Ort });
  }

function onFormSubmit(e) 
{
    var targetCell = e.range.offset(0, e.range.getNumColumns(), 1, 1);
}
  
  function myFunction() {
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    try {
      lock.waitLock(10000); // wait 5 seconds try to get lock
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
    }
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
    lock.releaseLock();
    
  }
```

And there

```
var Termin = meinKalender.createEvent(Titel, Dienstbeginn, Dienstende, { description: Beschreibung, location: Ort });
```

gives the error
when i run it over trigger onchange.

when i run it from script it was ok no error

can you give me based on both scripts a solution that i can give an trigger maybe get  or post form?

Comment: sorry but please make xxx on the ids i have seen it tolate by my post.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function myfunk() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1o9JYQlPDda9_ufudrdYsxFtU-jjvwIeyR-yJrC5qOWw').getSheetByName("Ausgang");
  var KalenderID = 'xxx@group.calendar.google.com';
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(KalenderID);
  const [a, b, c, d] = sh.getRange("A2:D2").getValues().flat();
  var dta = new Date(a);
  dta.setHours(b.getHours());
  dta.setMinutes(b.getMinutes());
  var dtc = new Date(c);
  dtc.setHours(d.getHours());
  dtc.setMinutes(d.getMinutes());
  var e = sh.getRange('E2').getValue();
  var f = sh.getRange('F2').getValue();
  var g = sh.getRange('G2').getValue();
  cal.createEvent(e, dta, dtc, { description: f, location: g });
  //call your other function here
}
```

Comment: sorry could you please mask the ids? I missed it when I sent the post and only changed it afterwards.

Now for your answer.
I'm a newbie but your answer seems to indicate how to get dates from the sheet into the calendar. This works for me without a doubt, but not with the selected trigger onchange. because it is started before all the data is available.

In short, how do I trigger the trigger when all the data is in the sheet and not before

Comment: Sorry I should have done that on my own